# How to select all keyframes from left or right having current frame as pivot?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I've been doing some animation with tons of keyframes and when I need to apply some change, I spend a lot of time selecting keyframes on dopesheet (pressing B, select all I want and perform change)

but this is very time consuming, I was hoping for some shortcut where I could select all keyframes from the left or right based on the current frame

script would work too,  I have to clue to start it by the way

any tips are welcome, thanks

Comment: Does using *Select* > *After Current Keyframe* or *Before Current Keyframe* help (or using `]` and `[` shortcuts) ? You could also try using *Between Selected markers*.

Answer (score 5):

Right click the key frame that should be the first of those you need selected and the hold Ctrl and either click the [ key for all keyframes on the left or the ] for all on the right (while Ctrl is held).

Comment: Kervin i tried that but it didnt work for me. do you know why? i was doing everything that you said

Comment: In Blender 2.8 the `[` or `]` keys appeared to work for me *without* holding the control key.

Answer (score 0):

CTRL + Shift, Click to the left or right of the playhead to select accordingly